# London Ale III Fast

Tags: fermentation, yeast

I just brewed a NEIPA and fermented it with London ale III. I pitched the yeast 2 and a half days ago and it started fermenting around 6 hours later.

I wanted to dry hop at high Krausen but when I opened the fermenter the Krausen had already dropped. I took a gravity reading and it had dropped to 1.018 from an OG of 1.064 already.

Is that anything to worry about? I pitched at 20 degrees Celsius so 68 F and that's bang in the middle of what's recommended so there shouldn't be any problems there.

Just checking and the airlock is still bubbling every 30 seconds or so. Just curious where the Krausen went so fast because I wanted to dry hop at high Krausen.

It's a 12 litre batch

Comment: London Ale III is quick.  I use it a lot and my beers are close to done fermenting in 4 days.  Of course, I warm it and leave it sit so it can clean up.  For my NEIPAs, I usually pitch about 48 hours in, but on the last one I did it at 24 hours.  I use a Tilt so I can monitor SG progress (not for the exact SG) and you can see it on the graphs.  This current beer went from 1.055 to 1.020 in 30 hours.

Comment: Wow that is very quick! Do you mean you dry hop 48 hours in instead of pitch?

Comment: yes, dry hop, not pitch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that that you missed High Krausen, but on the positive side all is not lost. Sounds like you had VERY good fermentation conditions and healthy yeast. While I've never had a beer reach final that fast I've found that when the conditions are good fermentation can happen a LOT faster than expected.

I would still dry hop it as planned. I am told that by dry hopping during the most active fermentation that some of the UNisomerized hop gets deposited on the side of your fermentor while leaving just the good stuff. Personally I've not found a huge difference between dry hopping during "High Krausen" and later. I would just stick as close to the recipe as you can and enjoy what sounds like a great beer.

Of course the best thing to do would be to repeat this recipe exactly only this time be ready for the quick fermentation get your hop addition in during "High Krausen" and see if you can tell the difference.

Cheers!

Comment: That's good to hear! Thanks! I was worried the yeast was bad or something but it sounds like the opposite.